# Item in zabbix does not display data

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

From the beginning, I have created a template that includes discovery, item prototypes, and trigger prototypes. In the configuration file, I have defined the necessary data for querying a service. After executing a Python script for all services, a value of 200 is returned, indicating that the service is functioning.

For all items in the pre-production environment, these values are correctly displayed. However, in the production environment, one of the items does not show any value, even though the script on the server returns a value of 200.

Please help me diagnose this issue; what could be the problem?

[image]